# How to show the first 5 character in text value and rest of them in ***** in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I have a requirement to show the first 5 character in text value and rest of them in *****.

Example:- 
HelloSalesforce  would be Hello**********

Comment: Downvote from me because this question doesn't show any attempt at research, and comes across as a "Do it for me" request (rather than a "Help me with part X of problem Y" request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of working with strings.

```
string str = 'HelloSalesforce';
string subStr = str.subString(0,5);
string encryptedString = str.subString(5, str.length()).replaceAll('[a-zA-Z]', '*');
string finalStr = subStr + encryptedString;
```

This will give you the answer you are looking for.

A regex is being used here to find the characters from position 5 onwards in your original string. Once found, it will replace those characters with an asterix value.

Hope this helps. You can also look at the apex [String Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm).